# How to interconversion between privatekey and keystore with password in interactive console

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

When I execute `geth attach` attaching a active geth node into a interactive console .
I could use keystore and password to sendTransaction .  But now I only know the raw privateKey，How to execute sendTransaction ? And how to generate keystore based on the raw privateKey?

From [importing-an-unencrypted-private-key](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/account-management.html#importing-an-unencrypted-private-key),we can transform privateKey to keystore, but how to get keystore from privateKey?